# Wordpress thumbs

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I´m having, in lack of better words, a hell of a time finding out how to use an image as thumbnail on my wordpress site.

What I want, is a thumbnail on my index.php and another, or larger repesentation of the image on my single.php. The problem with the thumb, is that it is not displaying in a correct scale.

All I´ve gotten so far, is the featured image, but this does not work as I want it to.

Check out what I´ve gotten so far, and it might give an ide to what I need.

http://petterstensig.com/  keep in mind I am quite new to wordpress..

Is it possible to upload two differnt images, one thumb and one large?

Any help will be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: "What I want, is a thumbnail on my index.php and another, or larger repesentation of the image on my single.php." Correct me if im wrong, but thats what I see.

Comment: True. What I need is to scale the thumb correctly. As you see, the thumb is not viewing as I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> True. What I need is to scale the thumb correctly. As you see, the
>   thumb is not viewing as I want it. – Hyperpedro

Okay cool, thats a simple case of setting the thumbnail size.

So in `functions.php` add:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true );`

This will crop the image to the size you specify.

Also read this [good tutorial](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/).